# Running Beats with docker or without?

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat, elastic-beats

As Beats a Data shippers, and they suppose to ship files, metrics, and so on, from a machine, is it a good approach to run beats with docker, as in this way beats is containerized?

I have currently the issue that I want to ship log files from an application, and if I install filebeats with docker, I have to provide somehow the log to the container. Is it a good approach to do something like this with docker, or should I normally install Filebeats, configure and run it on the machine without a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a strict rule, but I would use the same approach for your application as for the Beats — either containerize both or neither. That will also help you keep the expectations and setups aligned: logging to a file vs stdout and how to collect that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that "either containerize both or neither" would be the best answer for my question, and I will stick to it.